# What would be best to say at a 7 Eleven after I get my change?

Tags: word-choice

I heard people say both Domo or Arigato?  Wondering which would be best to use and what are the different situations where I should use one or the other. Also would it be inappropriate to use Arigato gozaimasu?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41838/7810

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/465/542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally say おねがいします when I offer items to the counter. Anyway, どうも or ありがとうございます are fine.